MUI Datagrid pro dynamic columns and column pinning maximum depth reached error
I am using MUI's datagrid pro. I have 1 fixed column that is to be pinned and others are generated dynamically based on a api call but when I try to generate these columns dynamically then I face this error "maximum depth reached".
Generated columns dynamically
If i don't pin that column then it works fine
Code is below:
    const {comparableDates,timeFilterType} = useSelector((state:IRootState) => state.dashboard)
    const { filteredVesselIds } = useSelector(
        (state: IRootState) => state.filter
        );
        const [tableFirst,setTableFirst] = useState<supplierTableType>({columns:[],rows:[],pinnedRows:{bottom:[]}})
        const [tableSecond,setTableSecond] = useState<supplierTableType|null>(null)

    const [allTabs,setAllTabs] = useState([
        {
            name: getQuarterMonthYear(comparableDates.compareFirst.startDate,timeFilterType),
            value: "compareFirst",
            component:(
                <SupplierEvalDataGrid
                    columns={tableFirst.columns}
                    rows={tableFirst.rows}
                    pinnedRows={tableFirst.pinnedRows}
                />
            ),
        },
    ])
    const [selectedTab, setSelectedTab] = useState(allTabs[0].value);
    const {showErrorToast} = useToast()
    const handleChange = (_: React.SyntheticEvent, newValue: string) => {
        setSelectedTab(newValue);
    };

    const fetchSupplierEvaluationDetails = async (dateObj:datePeriodType,isSecond?:boolean) => {
        const data = await getSupplierEvaluationDetails(filteredVesselIds,dateObj.startDate,dateObj.endDate,"","").catch(() => showErrorToast("Failed to fetch supplier evaluation data"));
        console.log("data",data)
        if(data && data.tableColumns && data.tableRows) {
            const newTableData = {columns:data.tableColumns,rows:data.tableRows,pinnedRows:data.pinnedRows}
            const newTabComponent = <SupplierEvalDataGrid {...newTableData} />;

            if (isSecond && comparableDates.compareSecond) {
                setTableSecond(newTableData);
                setAllTabs(prevTabs => {
                    return prevTabs.map(tab => tab.value === "compareSecond" ? { ...tab, component: newTabComponent } : tab);
                });
            } else {
                setTableFirst(newTableData);
                setAllTabs(prevTabs => {
                    return prevTabs.map(tab => tab.value === "compareFirst" ? { ...tab, component: newTabComponent } : tab);
                });
            }
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if(comparableDates.compareFirst) {
            fetchSupplierEvaluationDetails(comparableDates.compareFirst)
        }
        if(comparableDates.compareSecond) {
            fetchSupplierEvaluationDetails(comparableDates.compareSecond,true)
        }
    },[comparableDates,filteredVesselIds])

    return (
            <Grid container>
                <Grid item md={12} xs={12}>
                    <SupplierEvalTabsContainer>
                        <SupplierEvalTabs
                            value={selectedTab}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            aria-label="Supplier Eval Tabs"
                            variant="scrollable"
                            scrollButtons="auto"
                        >
                            {allTabs.map(tab => (
                                <Tab
                                    key={tab.value}
                                    label={tab.name}
                                    value={tab.value}
                                    {...a11yProps(tab.value)}
                                />
                            ))}
                        </SupplierEvalTabs>
                    </SupplierEvalTabsContainer>
                    {allTabs.map(tab => (
                        <CustomTabPanel
                            key={tab.value}
                            value={tab.value}
                            selectedTab={selectedTab}
                        >
                            {tab.component}
                        </CustomTabPanel>
                    ))}
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
    );
};

SupplierEvalDatagrid code -
(If i remove pinned columns then it works fine)
const SupplierEvalDataGrid = ({
    columns,
    rows,
    pinnedRows,
}: SupplierEvalDataGridType) => {
    console.log("columns",columns)

    return (
    <SupplerEvalDataGridTable
        columns={columns}
        rows={rows}
        hideFooter
        pinnedRows={pinnedRows}
        initialState={{ pinnedColumns: { left: ["PONumber"] } }}
        getRowHeight={() => "auto"}
        columnHeaderHeight={80}
    />
)};

I tried everything I could think of but no solution.
I want the PONumber column to be fixed.

It is fixed now. I was using "flex" property on the pinned column and when I removed it guess what ? It is working LMAO. Idk the reason but GG.
